# Assuming the Gospels are eye-witness accounts, how were certain events recorded where Jesus was alone?

Tags: words-of-jesus, clarity-of-scripture

For instance, the temptation in the desert. It was only Jesus and Satan there. Who could have recorded that?

Or the prayers of Jesus in the garden of Gethsemane? Jesus went up alone while the disciples slept. Who could have recorded the words He spoke there as an eye witness?

Comment: The simplest explanation is that Jesus told his disciples afterwards.

Comment: That seems simple enough. Although for Gethsemane His disciples would have definitely had to ask Him post resurrection.

Comment: @JairCrawford Could have also been in Gethsemane when he told them to pray. “Teacher, what have you been praying about?” “I’ve been praying: ‘My Father, if it is possible, may this cup be taken from me. Yet not as I will, but as you will.’ Now pray, and stay awake this time!”

Comment: It is not claimed by anyone that any of the Gospels is **only** an eyewitness account. All of them contain at least something that the author could not have seen for himself.

Comment: @DJClayworth Good point.  In fact Luke's Gospel is likely entirely investigative reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Using Occam's razor, there is no reason to expect a supernatural medium for the transmission of this information to the disciples. Jesus spent three years with his disciples. They had plenty of time to sit around the campfire, telling stories.

Answer (score 0):

It is not wise to "assume the Gospels are eye-witness accounts."

1. At most, only two Gospels--Matthew and John--were.

   - Both were among the original Twelve Apostles (Matthew 10:1-4; Luke 6:12-16)
   - Luke admits in the opening verses of his account that he was *not* an eye-witness [Luke 1:1-4].
   - We first read of Mark in Acts 12; years after Jesus had ascended into heaven.
2. As to how certain events in Jesus' private life could have been recorded, I think a quote from one who *was* an eye-witness, *and* of the Twelve, suffices:

   - 2 Peter 1:20, 21 [MEV]:  "20 But know this first of all, that no prophecy of the Scripture is a matter of one’s own interpretation. 21 For no prophecy at any time was produced by the will of man, but holy men moved by the Holy Spirit spoke from God."

Comment: My belief is that Mark is close enough to eye-witness testimony as there is a very early and long-standing tradition that Mark was Peter's personal secretary who transcribed Peter's account to him to put into writing.